# Factoring polynomials in $\Bbb Z_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, ring-theory

a). Factor $f(x) = x^3 + 4x^2 + 5x + 2$ completely over $\Bbb Z_7$.

b). Give two different factorizations of $x^2 + x + 8$ in $\Bbb Z_{10}[x]$.

I have found the zeros of both of these but I am having trouble finding a way to factor both of these. Is there any efficient method of factorization? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll get the same answers than in your last question: try $0,1,\cdots,7$ (idem $10$) and check if they're roots. If you want a factorization algorithm for $\Bbb Z_n$ you should ask that.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD For example. I got that $6$ is a root of a) But when I factor out $x-6$, I am getting a fraction. That is why I asked. I took what I asked in the last question and did it here.

Comment: $(x-6)(x-3)$ aka $(x+4)(x+7)$ is one.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I posted an answer below. Is that correct?

Comment: @Nid: The quadratic mod $10$ has an additional factorization that I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

a) $6$ is a zero. $(x-6) = (x+1)$. So $\frac {x^3 +4x^2 +5x +2}{x+1} = (x+1)(x+2)$

b) $x^2 + x +8 = x^2 -9x + 8 = (x-1)(x-8) = (x+9)(x+2)$.